# How to get r.js optimizer to combine all modules in a project into one file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, requirejs, r.js

From experimenting with the r.js optimizer, it seems that there is no way for your final index.html file to just reference a single script and never make any async calls to other scripts during the lifetime of a user's session (unless they reload the page of course).  From my experience, it looks like it creates a bunch of combined groups of optimized files which can be referenced when needed?  This seems counterintuitive to most combine scripts where you end up with just one combined/optimized js file that is in the correct order.  Can anyone help explain my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's how r.js works, it optimize your dependencies into one or multiple file (you'd use `include` option to get all your file togheter).

Although, this build will keep require.js script file out of the build. But, after the build, you can combine require.js (or minimal AMD implementation like almond.js) at the top of your builded file and it will all work mostly fine (some problem may occur depending on how you bootstrap your app, but most of the time those issues are pretty easy to resolve).

To combine the files easily, you can use tools like `grunt.js` (I really recommend it to you as it can do much more and is really a must have in frontend developpement workflow). If you work with backbone app, you can checkout (Backbone Boilerplate)[https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate] and their grunt implementation.